# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'image' error message

Tags: python, tuples

```
import pygame

#Colours used throughout the game
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
BackGround = ('D:\Idea 2\sky_colour_image.jpg', [0,0])

# Screen dimensions
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

#Player class
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

#Player image
def __init__(self):



    super().__init__()

    # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
    # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
    width = 40
    height = 40
    self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
    self.image.fill(BLUE)

    # Set a referance to the image rect.
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    # Set speed vector of player
    self.change_x = 0
    self.change_y = 0

    # List of sprites we can bump against
    self.level = None

def update(self):
    """ Move the player. """
    # Gravity
    self.calc_grav()

    # Move left/right
    self.rect.x += self.change_x

    # See if we hit anything
    block_hit_list =     pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,self.level.platform_list, False)
    for block in block_hit_list:
        # If we are moving right,
        # set our right side to the left side of the item we hit
        if self.change_x > 0:
            self.rect.right = block.rect.left
        elif self.change_x < 0:
            # Otherwise if we are moving left, do the opposite.
            self.rect.left = block.rect.right

    # Move up/down
    self.rect.y += self.change_y

    # Check and see if we hit anything
    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
    for block in block_hit_list:

        # Reset our position based on the top/bottom of the object.
        if self.change_y > 0:
            self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
        elif self.change_y < 0:
            self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

        # Stop our vertical movement
        self.change_y = 0

def calc_grav(self):

    if self.change_y == 0:
        self.change_y = 1
    else:
        self.change_y += .35

    # See if we are on the ground.
    if self.rect.y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height and self.change_y >= 0:
        self.change_y = 0
        self.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height

def jump(self):


    # move down a bit and see if there is a platform below us.
    # Move down 2 pixels because it doesn't work well if we only move down
    # 1 when working with a platform moving down.
    self.rect.y += 2
    platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
    self.rect.y -= 2

    # If it is ok to jump, set our speed upwards
    if len(platform_hit_list) > 0 or self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
        self.change_y = -10

# Player-controlled movement:
def go_left(self):   
    self.change_x = -6

def go_right(self):
    self.change_x = 6

def stop(self):
    self.change_x = 0


class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self, width, height):
    super().__init__()

    self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
    self.image.fill(GREEN)

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


class Level(object):


def __init__(self, player):

    self.platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.player = player


# Update everythign on this level
def update(self):
    self.platform_list.update()
    self.enemy_list.update()

def draw(self, screen):

    # Draw the background
    screen.fill(BLUE)

    # Draw all the sprite lists that we have
    self.platform_list.draw(screen)
    self.enemy_list.draw(screen)

# Background class
class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

  def __init__(self, image_file, location):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)  #call Sprite initializer
    self.image = pygame.image.load("D:\Idea 2\sky_colour_image.jpg")
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.left, self.rect.top = location



# Create platforms for the level
class Level_01(Level):


def __init__(self, player):

    # Call the parent constructor
    Level.__init__(self, player)

    # Array with width, height, x, and y of platform
    level = [[210, 70, 500, 500],
             [210, 70, 200, 400],
             [210, 70, 600, 300],
             ]

    # Go through the array above and add platforms
    for platform in level:
        block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
        block.rect.x = platform[2]
        block.rect.y = platform[3]
        block.player = self.player
        self.platform_list.add(block)


def main():

pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
size = [SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Platformer Jumper")

# Create the player
player = Player()

# Create all the levels
level_list = []
level_list.append( Level_01(player) )

# Set the current level
current_level_no = 0
current_level = level_list[current_level_no]

active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
player.level = current_level

player.rect.x = 340
player.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.rect.height
active_sprite_list.add(player)

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()



# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.go_left()
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.go_right()
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.jump()


        screen.fill([255, 255, 255])
        screen.blit(BackGround.image, BackGround.rect)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.change_x < 0:
                player.stop()
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.change_x > 0:
                player.stop()

    # Update the player.
    active_sprite_list.update()

    # Update items in the level
    current_level.update()

    # If the player gets near the right side, shift the world left (-x)
    if player.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
        player.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH

    # If the player gets near the left side, shift the world right (+x)
    if player.rect.left < 0:
        player.rect.left = 0


    current_level.draw(screen)
    active_sprite_list.draw(screen)



    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()


if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

So far this is supposed to be (nothing exciting yet) a simple platform jumper with sky backgrouns. Creating a game for a computing project, not that experienced in python. Aim to be adding in moving platforms etc soon, if anyone could help with that or the error I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Where's the error? And couldn't you narrow it down first instead of posting your entire code?

Comment: Please [edit] your question down to a [mcve], with emphasis on the "minimal"... you've dumped a _lot_ of code on us, and probably most of it has nothing to do with the error you're receiving.  Instead, please include the _full_ stack trace.  A stack trace is how the Python interpreter tries to explain what went wrong, where, and why... which are _exactly_ the questions you want answered.  (It will also tell you which classes and methods were in use when the error occurred, and thus are likely to end up in your MCVE.)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are asking an object (looks like `self` here) and asking it for the image that is part of it.  BUT the tuple doesn't have an attribute of image.

Not sure here, but I think you may have an indent error.

`def __init__()` should be indented since it is a method on your class.  Python does not use curly braces, but space is significant.